# How do I fix wall paint that was removed with tape?

Tags: painting

Before painting I sanded all walls and then cleaned. I painted ceiling first then walls. Before painting walls I taped off a ceiling which was completely dry. Painted walls and the following day removed tape. Seeing wall paint was also being removed I used a knife to cut where ceiling and wall meet. It did not matter, paint was removed around the whole bathroom.

How do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Taping isn't commonly done in cases like that, but the issue is obviously a poor paint bond. Maybe you had dust on the wall, or maybe the sanding wasn't adequate at the corner.

Anyway, use a high-quality brush and re-edge your walls. A good technique is to hold the brush at a 45 degree angle with respect to the wall, press it in to feather out the bristles, then twitch the brush as you move along horizontally. This allows extremely fine control of paint flow. There are plenty of good videos on YouTube, too.

I also recommend removing tape almost immediately after painting, for two reasons:

1. Dried paint acts as a film, which obviously has to be torn or cut to prevent damage and ugly edges.
2. Torn or cut edges are much more harsh than edges that dry after removing the tape. They can shrink and soften as they dry, resulting in a nicer finished appearance.

Answer (score 1):

Fix this issue by removing the flaky/chipped paint with a scraper, sanding (no finer than 120 grit) the edge. This is to remove loose paint, provide a key and to taper the remaining paint edge, so you do not have a hard ridge line showing through. If it has gone down to bare plaster, ensure you mist-coat it first (watered-down paint).

Avoid "general-purpose" masking tapes as their adhesive is too aggressive. Peel it off at an angle down from the ceiling, keeping your hand in front of, and near near the point that it is coming away from the wall.